# Laravel withCount gives error

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel and in am learning process. I am developing a blog. In one page i am getting all the posts along with their total number of comments against each post. Getting all posts works fine but when i use the **withCount** method it gives me error.

```
public function posts() {
    $posts['posts'] = Post::with('comments') -> get();
    return view('dashboard.posts', $posts);
}
```

As I am new so i searched google as well but was not able to find the answer. Please help me with this.

This is the error

`RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php line 20:
Call to undefined relationship [comments] on model [App\Post].`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, actually i was missing comments model so here is the answer

In Post controller

```
$posts['posts'] = Post::withCount(['comments']) -> get();
```

In Post Model

```
function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```